# file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading

Tags: php

I am trying  to make a simple file_get_contents(https://some.api) in my code, but, while the URL works in the browser, it doesn't in php. I always get the following error:

```
file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading
```

I already tried some suggestions from similar questions in Stack Overflown like using stream_context_create():

```
$arrContextOptions=array(
    "ssl"=>array(
        "verify_peer"=>false,
        "verify_peer_name"=>false,
    ),
);  
$geoData = file_get_contents($requestUrl, false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
```

But it still doesn't work. PHP SLL also seems to be ok:

```
~ » php -i | grep -i openssl                                                                                                                         user@localhost
SSL Version => OpenSSL/3.0.3
libSSH Version => libssh/0.9.6/openssl/zlib
libmongoc SSL library => OpenSSL
openssl
OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 3.0.3 3 May 2022
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
Openssl default config => /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf
openssl.cafile => no value => no value
openssl.capath => no value => no value
Native OpenSSL support => enabled
```

Comment: Looks like the remote end is closing the connection. Refer to the provider's docs for proper connection procedure and/or troubleshooting.

Comment: You cannot connect to the server because the crawler/bot is blocked by the web server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely due to this issue:  https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=79589

An IIS or equivalent non-compliant daemon is not following the SSL specification and OpenSSL is raising an error because of this.  PHP does not provide any method to work around it and since you cannot pass the necessary SSL_OP_IGNORE_UNEXPECTED_EOF flag to OpenSSL the connection fails with an error.

For reference:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_CTX_set_options.html

> SSL_OP_IGNORE_UNEXPECTED_EOF
>
> ```
> Some TLS implementations do not send the mandatory close_notify alert on shutdown. If the application tries to wait for the
> ```
>
> close_notify alert but the peer closes the connection without sending
> it, an error is generated. When this option is enabled the peer does
> not need to send the close_notify alert and a closed connection will
> be treated as if the close_notify alert was received.

Answer (score 0):

Conclusion, you need upgrade your php version

In my case using php 7.4, temporarily (while I upgrade) I use '@file_get_contents' instead of 'file_get_contents'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).