# XML import - SSL operation failed with code 1

Tags: php, laravel, ssl

Laravel 9 App, running well with docker desktop on Windows 10 - WSL2 Ubuntu.
Here is my load function code in controller responsible for import xml file:

```
public function load($fileName)
    {
        $filePath = 'https://___.xml';
        $xmlString = file_get_contents($filePath);
        $xmlObject = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);

        $json = json_encode($xmlObject);
        $phpArray = json_decode($json, true);

        dd($phpArray);
    }
```

Im getting such error:

`file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading`

How can I handle this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148701/file-get-contents-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-failed-to-enable-crypto

Comment: Reading more into this, it appears to be a bug. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72536921/file-get-contents-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-openssl-error-messages-e